# Giving an error with expo-camera, TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoCamera.CameraType.back')

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'd like help regarding the test code in the expo-camera, I am using expo go and once I run the code, it gives me this error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoCamera.CameraType.back'), here is the documentation for the expo-camera: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/ , I am currently using expocamera 12.3.0 and have used navigation.navigate to navigate to this tab thanks ! and here is the code I directly copied from the site

```
import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [type, setType] = useState(CameraType.back);
  const [permission, requestPermission] = Camera.useCameraPermissions();

  if (!permission) {
    // Camera permissions are still loading
    return <View />;
  }

  if (!permission.granted) {
    // Camera permissions are not granted yet
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          We need your permission to show the camera
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={requestPermission} title="grant permission" />
      </View>
    );
  }


  function toggleCameraType() {
    setType((current) => (
      current === CameraType.back ? CameraType.front : CameraType.back
    ));
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera style={styles.camera} type={type}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={toggleCameraType}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Flip Camera</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    margin: 64,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: fixed it, just changed CameraType.back into Camera.Constants.Type.back, solved